# Change HELO host name when sending email

Tags: php, symfony1, smtp, dns, sendmail

A customer's website address is **customerswebpage.com** (not the real one, of course). The server itself has it's host name configured to **server.customerswebpage.com**, which has no A or MX type DNS records. This causes many web servers to refuse mail from this server.

Is there an easy and/or neat way to change the HELO address the server identifies itself as? The site is built on the **Symfony** framework version 1.0 and we're using the **sfMail** plugin to send the mail. The only solution I could think of so far is taking a copy of the whole plugin and modifying it to suit our needs, as the hostname is used only internally.

Maybe even more importantly, do you think we could say this is a DNS misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HELO needs to be changed in server's MTA and not in php.

http://www.sendmail.org/m4/whoami.html

You should probably just add the missing A and MX DNS records for **server.customerswebpage.com** and not change HELO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what we ended up doing. After adding the A record for the domain the mails started to go through to even the pickiest servers.

Answer (score 1):

Mail servers can be really picky, and it is by no means granted that adding a proper `A` and `PTR` record for the server will resolve all issues. It is usually most hassle-free to use an external [smarthost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host) (for example via your ISP or a dedicated service) for outgoing mail, and let them worry about deliveries.

The **sfMail** package is based on **PHPMailer**, and that package stores the HELO host name in `$helo`. Perhaps you can overload the [sfMail phpMailer](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/trunk/lib/symfony/addon/sfMail/PhpMailer.class.php?rev=1) class and set that variable?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Overriding phpMailer would require overriding all the other sfMail classes as well, because the classes the factory uses seem to be hardcoded and the one to use is chosen with a switch-case block. Using a smarthost would be smart (no pun intended) but setting one up would be a bit over budget for this project.

Answer (score 0):

A way for avoiding this problem is to use sfMail with SMTP. So you can send your E-Mail with your real Mailserver so the SPF and MX Records are right.

Comment: Unfortunately that server seems to be our only option, even the customer uses it for mass mailing. Which seem to be failing miserably too...